# How to add iframe to Slide in material-auto-rotating-carousel

Tags: css, iframe, material-ui, carousel

I want to replace the image in the carousel slide with a loom video.

Can anyone see how to replace the media img with an iframe in [material-auto-rotating-carousel](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-auto-rotating-carousel)?

```
const AutoRotatingCarouselModal = ({ handleOpen, setHandleOpen, isMobile }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Button onClick={() => setHandleOpen({ open: true })}>Open carousel</Button> */}
      <AutoRotatingCarousel
        // label="Get started"
        open={handleOpen.open}
        onClose={() => setHandleOpen({ open: false })}
        onStart={() => setHandleOpen({ open: false })}
        autoplay={false}
        mobile={isMobile}
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      >
        <Slide
          // media={
          //   <img src="http://www.icons101.com/icon_png/size_256/id_79394/youtube.png" />
          // }
          <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0;"><iframe src="https://www.loom.com/embed/f477ff57" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
          mediaBackgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#1565C0" }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#42A5F5" }}
          title="Monitor "
          subtitle="Open."
        />
        <Slide
          media={
            <img src="http://www.icons101.com/icon_png/size_256/id_80975/GoogleInbox.png" />
          }
          mediaBackgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: blue[400] }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: blue[600] }}
          title="stations"
          subtitle="Review "
        />
        <Slide
          media={
            <img src="http://www.icons101.com/icon_png/size_256/id_76704/Google_Settings.png" />
          }
          mediaBackgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: blue[600] }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: blue[800] }}
          title="Focus "
          subtitle="The Force is a metaphysical and ubiquitous power in the Star Wars fictional universe."
        />
      </AutoRotatingCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();  
  const [handleOpen, setHandleOpen] = useState({ open: false });
  const handleClick = () => {
    setHandleOpen({ open: true });
  };
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)");
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ButtonBase
          focusRipple
          className={classes.image}
          onClick={handleClick}
          focusVisibleClassName={classes.focusVisible}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <span
            className={classes.imageSrc}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${DS})`,
            }}
          />
          <span className={classes.imageBackdrop} />
          <span className={classes.imageButton}>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              variant="subtitle1"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.imageTitle}
            >
              DESIGN
              <span className={classes.imageMarked} />
            </Typography>
          </span>
          
        </ButtonBase>
        
      <AutoRotatingCarouselModal
        isMobile={matches}
        handleOpen={handleOpen}
        setHandleOpen={setHandleOpen}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't great, but it's the best I've been able to come up with:

media={
<iframe
src="https://www.loom.com/embed/f4777"
frameborder="0"
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
// style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
>

}